# background color not inherited

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The background and the padding are not applying and the css is not overriding the bootstrap style and when i keep the container style the css display style is not applied.

check the below code:

```css
body{
    background-color: #f5d9d5;
    font-family: 'Nunito' , sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tcontainer bg-light p-2">
      <img src="data:image/.." alt="">
      <h4>ping pong score keeper</h4>
      <div class="panel ">
        <h3><span class="p1">0</span> to <span class="p2">0</span></h3>
        <p>Use the buttons below to keep score</p>
        <h4>playing to 
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select></h4>
      </div>
      <button>P1 +1</button>
      <button>P2 +2</button>
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>


  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

[how the website appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I3S1.png)

Comment: Do you have `background-color: inherit`? If not, it will not be inherited by elements and will we default `transparent`

Comment: i see but the panel div inherited the background color why do you think that may be

Comment: i tried it nothing changed

Comment: You provided only CSS for `body`, so I can't comment on why something works and something not. Maybe it has same background color, maybe it does have inherited background color, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Try adding !important to the background-color css property. Your CSS property is getting overwritten. adding !important should make the results look like follows:

```css
body{
    background-color: #f5d9d5 !important;
    font-family: 'Nunito' , sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tcontainer bg-light p-2">
      <img src="data:image/.." alt="">
      <h4>ping pong score keeper</h4>
      <div class="panel ">
        <h3><span class="p1">0</span> to <span class="p2">0</span></h3>
        <p>Use the buttons below to keep score</p>
        <h4>playing to 
          <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select></h4>
      </div>
      <button>P1 +1</button>
      <button>P2 +2</button>
      <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
    

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the response but the body background color is working fine i am talking about the tcontainer div you should notice a .bg-light
and to avoid the override problem i put the bootstrap link before the css link i'll add an image so that things wwould be clearer

Comment: The issue here seems that the background is extremely light, and thus looks like it has no effect. I tried applying bg-warning and bg-danger and those appear light. I also noticed that you have added bootstrap 3.4.1 . This version of bootstrap did not have a definition for bg-light. for that you might want to consider upgrading the version.

Comment: please consider upvoting the comment, answer or any resource that solved your issue so people referring to this may know how it was fixed. I am also adding another answer marking the exact problem so future references might get help from it. Please consider marking it as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Link the Css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Then try to refresh the

Comment: it's linked the difference is that the file is named app instead of style that's all

Answer (score 0):

The bg-light class you are trying to apply to tcontainer is not working since the version of bootstrap that you are using here i.e. bootstrap 3.4.1 does not contain a definition for bg-light and bg-dark. Try updating the bootstrap version, since I don't see a mistake in the code itself.